# Savitzky-Golay filtering for large data set

Tags: r, filtering

I would like to apply a Savitzky-Golay filter (from `prospectr`package) to a set of samples taken for different areas of interest. Here is a sample of the data.

```
 > head(file,10)
   subject eye sample_num area sample_value
         1   L          1    1    -7.813280
         1   L          2    1    -7.816787
         1   L          3    1    -7.826342
         1   L          4    1    -7.799060
         1   L          5    1    -7.817019
         1   L          6    1    -7.845589
         1   L          7    1    -7.881824
         1   L          8    1    -7.969951
         1   L          9    1    -8.022991
         1   L         10    1    -8.118056


> dput(head(file))
 structure(list(subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), eye = structure(c(1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", "R"), class = "factor"), 
     sample_num = 1:6, area = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), sample_value = c(-7.81328047761194, 
-7.81678696801706, -7.82634248187633, -7.79906019616205, 
-7.81701949680171, -7.84558887846482)), .Names = c("subject", 
 "eye", "sample_num", "area", "sample_value"), row.names = c(NA, 
 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Values in sample_value correspond to eye position recorded for the left and right eye and were taken each millisecond.

What I want to do is apply the filter to the sample data in each area. I tried to use ddply from package plyr in order to split the file into subsets by subject, eye and area and apply the filter (I want to keep both the original sample values and the values obtained after filtering in a new column). The code is below.

```
newfile <- ddply(file, .(file$subject, file$eye, file$area), 
           function(x){
               x$sg_filtered <- savitzkyGolay(x$sample_value, 1,1,3)
               return(x)})
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "sg", value = c(-0.00653100213219515,  : 
  replacement has 1838 rows, data has 1840
```

Presumably, this is because the column containing the filtered data will not have a corresponding value for the first and last sample_value in each area. Is there a way to adjust the code so that I get NA for those and keep the two columns the same length? I would really appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

Comment: can you use `dput(head(file))` to return a reproducible sample. This is from the `prospectr` packacge correct?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I edited the question and used `dput(head(file))` as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pad the returned vector with `NA`s, you can just use `c()`:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
w <- 3 # must be odd number
out <- c(rep(NA, (w-1)/2), savitzkyGolay(x, 1, 1, w = w), rep(NA, (w-1)/2))
length(out)
# [1] 100
head(out)
# [1]         NA  1.0595920  0.1503429 -0.7147103  0.8222783  0.1658142
tail(out)
# [1]  0.01382324  0.41334027  1.06643511 -1.21151668 -1.27951576          NA
```